# Apple iOS distribution certificate has a new private key after reset

Tags: ios, xcode

I used XCode to download certificates after regenerating them.  I noticed the distribution certificate didn't have a private key in the key chain.  I saw that XCode now has a "reset" button so I used that.  The new certificate has a private key but with a different name.  It still worked though and allowed me to export and install an adhoc app.  Also we have two dev teams, could this be the other teams private key?

Answer (score 1):

When the certificate is first requested, the private key is generated and saved in the keychain on the Mac used to generate the request. Only this Mac will be able to actually sign the apps. As in your case, if you have more than one developer authorised to sign apps for distribution using this certificate, you'll need to export the private key from the original requesting machine, and import it into the keychain of other developers.

If you use the 'reset' button, it will revoke the existing certificate and issue a new certificate signing request from your Mac. This will also invalidate all provisioning profiles in the developer account that are tied to the previous certificate. Existing apps already in the iOS app store will be OK, but you will need to regenerate the provisioning profile with the new certificate for any new app signing.